# @Autowired annotation

Tags: spring

I have written a small code to check @Autowired annotation in Spring, here is my piece of code

```
public class Address 
{
    private String street;
    private String City;
    private String State;
    private String Country;

    /* getter setter here */       
}

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Customer 
{
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    // other getter setter here 

    @Autowired
    public void setAddress(Address address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

and springexample.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="address1" class="org.springexamples.Address">
            <property name="street" value="vihar" />
            <property name="city" value="dehradun" />
            <property name="state" value="Uttarakhand" />
            <property name="country" value="India" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="addres2" class="org.springexamples.Address">
            <property name="street" value="triveni vihar" />
            <property name="city" value="dehradun" />
            <property name="state" value="Uttarakhand" />
            <property name="country" value="India" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="customer" class="org.springexamples.Customer">
        <property name="name" value="deepak" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

and main class

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AutowiredQualifierTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springexample.xml");
        Customer cust = (Customer)context.getBean("customer");
        System.out.println(cust.getName() + "  " + cust.getAddress().getStreet());
    }
}
```

Ideally it should show an exception as two beans of the same type exist however its picking up bean with id="address1" so i am getting this bean behaviour.

Comment: Which version of spring you are using?

Answer (score 2):

No unique bean of type [org.springexamples.Address] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [address1, addres2]..exception is coming..and it is clearly saying right..so you have to use @Qualifier(your_required_beanid)

for example:
@Qualifier("Address1")
then it will consider id with address1 bean

Comment: for me its not showing an error.its wiring the customer with address1 which should not happen

Comment: how come ...whatever i have written in ecplise have pasted here so howcome its showing an error you but not to me???can you check the code once again...??

Comment: if i give one id as address and another id as address1 will it autowire by name? if yes than i read that @autowire tries to autowire by byType

Comment: hi..can you check your code once again..i think you had given qualifier annotation..so that only you imported that qualifier package..if not post the whole code..

Comment: hi..are you using..spring 3.0 If yes..i think it is a bug in spring 3.0,for me when i use spring 3.0 there is no exception,if i use spring latest 3.2 it is giving exception..

Comment: so try to use..spring latest version,then your problem will be solved..if your problem solved mark this as answer..

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown. I bet you are doing something wrong. I have tested you code, just to be hundred percent sure and it throws the exception.

Let's take a look to the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html):

> **3.4.5.1 Limitations and disadvantages of autowiring**
>
> Multiple bean definitions within the container may match the type specified by the setter method or constructor argument to be autowired. For arrays, collections, or Maps, this is not necessarily a problem. However for dependencies that expect a single value, this ambiguity is not arbitrarily resolved. ***If no unique bean definition is available, an exception is thrown***

Also, take a look to this [post](http://develop.nydi.ch/2010/12/spring-primary-bean-injection/).

Answer (score 1):

This will give you exception, when spring tries to autoware the address field, it will not find any bean with id address ...rather user Qualifer with proper id so that while autowaring it will pinck the porper object of address from 2 id [address1, address2].